# Hibernate @ManyToOne violates foreign key constraint

Tags: java, hibernate

I have person class which contains another object Title.

```
public class Person {

public Person(){
    titleId=new Title();
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private LongId;

@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER,targetEntity=Title.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "titleId", referencedColumnName = "titleId",columnDefinition="int",nullable=false)
private Title title;

...
...
}

@Entity
public class Title {
@Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
@Column(columnDefinition = "serial")
private int titleId;

@Id
private String title; }
```

When I try to insert Person object with below detail.

```
  Person p=new Person();
  Title t=new Title();
  t.setTitle("Mr.");
  p.setName("abc");
  p.setTitle(t);
  sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(p);
```

It's working fine and inserting title and person

But when I try to insert another person with same title, it fails

```
Person p=new Person();
Title t=new Title();
t.setTitle("Mr.");
p.setName("pqr");
p.setTitle(t);
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(p);
```

It's giving exception as below

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update on table
>   "person" violates foreign key constraint
>   "fk_9s5vdsvlj3nqy8btf3u1wgvqf"   Detail: Key (titleid)=(0)
>   is not present in table "title".

I can pass titleId and it will work, however there are chance that I don't have titleId available.

Comment: Except for the name  of the person, the two snippets are identical. So I don't see how one could work and the other could not. If the goal is to associate a person with an *existing* title, you need a reference to this *existing* title, by getting it from the database somehow. You shouldn't create a new one as your code does.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So hibernate will not automatically detect that it's already exists and use the same? I have to manually check everytime if exists and then use it or create new one? SaveOrUpdate will not save or update the child objects?

Comment: No, it won't. The only thing that identifies an entity uniquely is its ID. You could very well want two identical instances of Title, differing only by their ID.

Answer (score 1):

This has happened to me because I had meddled with various table names and the database was retaining old foreign key constraints (from previous test builds).
Try to drop the tables from your DB and let Hibernate re-create them.

Answer (score 0):

First You have to define OneToMany relation in Title entity something like below

```
@Entity
public class Title {
   @OneToMany(mappedBy="title", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,     orphanRemoval=true, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
}
```

Then to add person and Title you have to add person on title persons field.

```
Person p=new Person();
p.setName("pqr");
Title t=new Title();
t.setTitle("Mr.");
t.addPersons(p);
p.setTitle(t);
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(t);
```

Comment: Thanks Rishi, I want one way relation ship only. I don't  need persons object under title class. Still I have tried but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You got foreign key violation because you use title as id ( primary key of entity Title). Try this:

```
 @Entity
 public class Title {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int titleId;

    private String title; 
 }
```

Comment: I have not added it purpose fully, I want to keep primary key "Title" and "TitleId" will be generated by database using serial type of pg. I am not getting violation on title object but getting on person object.

Answer (score -1):

You have an error on your definition of the person ID. You have:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private LongId;
```

I think it should be:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long Id;
```

Maybe it cames from here ? :)